# Redondear Decimales en Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Quisiera preguntar si alguien sabe como hacer que solo se muestren 2 decimales (o 3) en un Label de tkinter.
Les propongo mi ejemplo:

```
guardabrazos = Label(ventana, text=f'Guardabrazos: {Guardabrazos} - [25,57 g]').grid(column=0, row=3)
```

`Guardabrazos` es un numero que varia dependiendo el precio el cual hayas comprado, entonces, depende que precios, sale con 5 o 6 decimales y el juego solo acepta hasta 2, entonces me gustaria poder hacer que el precio del guardabrazos es por ejemplo `7,645643645g - [25,57g]`, que quedara en `7,65g - [25,57g]`.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Un saludo

Comment: Utiliza `round(Guardabrazos,2)`

Comment: por si alguien tiene el mismo problema, gracias a Christian, la respuesta seria:

```guardabrazos = Label(ventana, text=f'Guardabrazos: {round(Guardabrazos, 2)} - [25,57 g]').grid(column=0, row=3)```

Comment: de nada, si deseas puedes responder a tu propia pregunta :)

Comment: ya que estas usando un formateador de cadenas también se puede text=f'Guardabrazos:{Guardabrazos:.2f}